# Latex : Images are not appearing in chapter1.tex but works in main.tex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I can see this is a common question. However, I dont find a solution to my problem. I write my master thesis in LaTex, and the images are not appearing in the pdf document when I compile. It does appear on the `main.tex` but not on the other chapters, such as `chapter1.tex`

**This is my document class and packages;**

```
\documentclass[
11pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
%liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
%toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
%parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
%nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textcolor{blue}{\arabic{footnote}}}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default

%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
%\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}

%\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

%\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including images
%\graphicspath{{/Figures}} % Location of the graphics files
\usepackage[]{graphics}
```

**This is what I did to display an image;**

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{/Figures/Electron}
  \caption[Execution time]{Execution time} 
    \label{fig:Execution time}
\end{figure}
```

The above code work and the images appear if I put in the **main.tex**, but if I try to put the images in the other chapters (Chapter1.tex) it fails to display.

Comment: I downloaded Masters/Doctoral Thesis LaTeX templates. Where chapters are in a different folders. Usually everything compile correctly. Such as equations, references etc. But only problem is with the images.

Comment: @Mass17 Can you a) make a compilable [mre] that shows how you include the chapters in your main file and all the code from the chapters necessary to compile your document b) show the resulting .log file including what error you get c) tell us where to get all the non-standard files like your documentclass.